# Heading table with other table content

Tags: mysql

CARATTERISTICA_SOTTOOGGETTO:

```
idT valore fkIdCaratteristica fkIdSottooggetto

 1    8          2                  1
 2   rosso       3                  1
 3    6          2                  2
 4   nero        3                  2
 5   100         4                  2
 6   150         4                  1
```

CARATTERISTICA:

```
idT    nome    unitaMisura 

 2     lama        cm
 3     colore    colore
 4     Peso        kg
```

I like to have

```
fkIdSottooggetto lama   colore   peso

        1         8     rosso    150
        2         6     nero     100
```

I don't know how to join the 2 tables to create this result

I tried but nothing ....

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called 'pivoting'. In your case I have used the second table only as a hint on how to display the results of he first table. It is not needed in the query itself.

```
SELECT fkIdSottooggetto,
 MAX(CASE WHEN fkIdCaratteristica=2 THEN valore END) lama,
 MAX(CASE WHEN fkIdCaratteristica=3 THEN valore END) colore,
 MAX(CASE WHEN fkIdCaratteristica=4 THEN valore END) peso
FROM CARATTERISTICA_SOTTOOGGETTO
GROUP BY fkIdSottooggetto
```

See here for a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f314a0/2).

In my solution I chose `max()` to aggregate the grouped values for each characteristic. It may be that in your application you want to have the `min` value or the `sum` of these values. But that is only relevant in case there is more than one value per `fkIdSottooggetto` and `fkIdCaratteristica` in your table.